# How can i upload multiple files in struts 1.3 using org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile[]

Tags: file-upload, struts, struts-1, multifile-uploader

In my form end user have the chance to add multiple files dynamically.so i have done this with the help of javascript. But problem is that i am using dynavalidator form, In this dynavalidator form i am mentioning like org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile[] array.

how can i do this .. please help me..

Answer (score 0):

its not possible with dynavalidator form use the action form Formfile like this you can add how many files do you want that many

private List formFiles = new ArrayList();

```
public List<FormFile> getUploads() {
    return this.formFiles;
}

public void setUploads(int iIndex, FormFile formFile) {
    this.formFiles.add(formFile);
}
```